# catching request on exception in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, exception, logging

I have few webservices in my solution, they use NLOG for logging into the database, I want to catch the Request whenever there is an Exception , currently all the request and response calls are being logged into the database and I want to change it log only the Requests upon exception ..I did some research but did not find any proper answer, if you could give me some example than it could be verymuch helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try Application_Error method in Global.asax. It can catch any unhandled exceptions of application.
Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/24395wz3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: For WCF, it would be better to implement IErrorHandler to catch unhandled exceptions.  `Global.asax` is specific to ASP.NET - what if the service is hosted in a Windows Service or a WinForm or something else?

Comment: In any event, OP is looking to log **only** exceptions, and is currently logging everything, so I don't think it's a case of unhandled exceptions as much as it's a case of filtering what actually gets logged.